# unity udp not receiving

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, udp, unityscript

i'm trying to make a networking script that will find all game servers on a LAN but i am running into some trouble; import System.Net.Sockets;

import System.Net.Sockets;

```
private var udp_server:UdpClient;
private var udp_client:UdpClient;
private var udp_port:int = 18000;
private var udp_broadcast_ip:IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse ("224.0.0.224");

private var selected:boolean = false;

private var udp_received_message:String;

function StartServer(){

    udp_server = new UdpClient(udp_port, AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
    var udp_endpoint:IPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(udp_broadcast_ip, udp_port);
    udp_server.Connect (udp_endpoint);

    InvokeRepeating("StartBroadcastUDP", 0.0,0.3);
}

function StartClient(){
    if(udp_client == null){
        udp_client = new UdpClient(udp_port);
        udp_client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(StartReceiveUDP), null);
        Debug.Log("Searching for udp");
    }
}

function StartBroadcastUDP(){
    var udp_broadcast_message:String = "GAME SERVER";

    if(udp_broadcast_message != ""){
        udp_server.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (udp_broadcast_message), udp_broadcast_message.Length);
    }
}

function StartReceiveUDP(result:IAsyncResult){
    Debug.Log("Searching for udp");
    var udp_endpoint:IPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, udp_port);
    var udp_received_message_byte:byte[];

    if(udp_client != null){
        udp_received_message_byte = udp_client.EndReceive(result, udp_endpoint);
    }else{
        return;
    }

    udp_client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(StartReceiveUDP), null);
    udp_received_message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(udp_received_message_byte);
    Debug.Log("Searching for udp");
}

function Update(){
    if(udp_received_message != null){
        Debug.Log("Received Message: " + udp_received_message);
    }
}

function OnGUI(){
    if(!selected){
        if(GUI.Button(Rect(0, 0, 50, 50), "Server")){
            StartServer();
            selected = true;
        }else if(GUI.Button(Rect(50, 0, 50, 50), "Client")){
            StartClient();
            selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

it seams that when i start receiving udp (BeginReceive in Startclient) it just plan doesn't to id. to make sure it is the case i added a few debug.logs and still got nothing

Comment: The `unityscript` language that Unity uses is pretty far from Javascript. Edited the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately async calls are somehow problematic in Unity. You can use blocking calls in threads or nonblocking calls in main thread (in Update methods).